# Render different classes based on Path NEXTJS

Tags: conditional-statements, next.js

I have a Header.JS file which has a navigation component, sometimes I need the left menu to render and sometimes I need the right one to render based on the page.

If my path is / I want to render

```
        <Navigation
          menu={menus?.left_menu}
          styles={styles}
          className={styles.leftMenu}
        />
```

if my path is anything else like /about, I want to render

```
        <Navigation
          menu={menus?.right_menu}
          styles={styles}
          className={styles.rightMenu}
        />
```

Is there an easy way to just look up what the path is and do a conditional based on the path of the current page?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Next.JS exposes the path via the [`router` module](https://nextjs.org/docs/api-reference/next/router).

You would first import the `useRouter` hook, and then initialise it in your functional component.

`router.pathname` would then be accessible to you, which would be the path of the page inside your NextJS application. If you wanted something more akin to what is in the URL bar for the user, you would use `router.asPath`.

You could also do this at a higher level and prop-drill the path as necessary to the needed component.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks @mattieTK

Was able to get that to work doing something like this

```js
export default function Header() {
  const router = useRouter()
  const path = router?.asPath // URL from router.

  if (path === '/homepage') {
    return (
      <>
        <a className={styles.skip} href="#page-content">
          Skip to Main Content
        </a>
    </>
  }
)
```